# XAML ListBox Items binding to an Activity

Tags: xaml, binding, listboxitem, workflow-activity

I'm using Microsoft Activity Library Designer; For some reasons I need to use ListBox to show some information in it.But I have a problem with it's *ItemsSource* binding.My Activity side property is like this:

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _selectedItems;
    public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedItems
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_selectedItems == null)
            {
                ObservableCollection<string> items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
                return items;
            }
            return _selectedItems;
        }
        set 
        { 
            _selectedItems = value;
        }
    }
```

And my XAML side code is like this:

```
....
<Button Content="Add Item" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0"
        Click="Button_Click" Margin="5, 0, 5, 5"/>

<Button Content="Remove Item" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1"
        Click="DelButton_Click" Margin="5, 0, 5, 5"/>
....
<ListBox x:Name="LstSelectedPosts" MinHeight="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ModelItem.Selecteditems, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
....
```

Now when I try to Add/Remove an item to/from this ListBox in ***Add Item*** and ***Remove Item*** buttons click event, debugger shows me an error that tells I can't modify the ListBox binding source.
So how can I change this Listbox's Items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there are some errors in your code that could cause the problem.
In the getter, I think you should have this.

```
if (_selectedItems == null)
{
   _selectedItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
}
return _selectedItems;
```

In your version, _selectedItems never get initialized.

In the Xaml code, when you set the ItemSource, you wrote `Seleceteditems` instead of `SelectedItems` this error doesn't cause an error when you compile but your listBox doesn't have its itemSource setted to the correct element.

And then, you didn't specify the source in

`ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ModelItem.Selecteditems, Mode=TwoWay}`

that means the source is by default, the DataContext of your object and that DataContext should be initialized with an object that has a public property named `ModelItem` which has in turn a public property named `Selecteditems`.
Hope it works.

Here is a small example.
in my xaml file

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListBox Height="287" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" x:Name="LstSelectedPosts" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="294" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Button Content="Add Item" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Click="Button_Click" Margin="321,110,68,170"/>
    <Button Content="Remove Item" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Click="DelButton_Click" Margin="321,147,68,129"/>
</Grid>
```

in my xaml.cs file

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private CDataContext _myCDataContext;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _myCDataContext = new CDataContext();
        DataContext = _myCDataContext;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _myCDataContext.Add();
    }

    private void DelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       _myCDataContext.Remove(LstSelectedPosts.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }


}
```

and my CDataContext class

```
 class CDataContext
{
    private int _count = 0;
    private ObservableCollection<string> _selectedItems;
    public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectedItems == null)
            {
                _selectedItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            }
            return _selectedItems;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedItems = value;
        }
    }

    public void Remove(string s)
    {
        SelectedItems.Remove(s);
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        SelectedItems.Add(_count.ToString());
        _count++;
    }
}
```